# How to pass the option "listings" to examplep

Tags: listings, examplep

I've been trying to pass the option `listings` to the [`examplep`](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/examplep/) package.

According to the [documentation](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/examplep/eurotex_2005_examplep.pdf) one can pass the options to activate the listing by doing `listings=yes`, `listings={}`. However, none of those works and I still get the error:

> Package examplep Error: Unknown option: listings (= yes) ...name opt@\@currname.\@currext\endcsname}

I checked on the source code, and I can't find any `listings` option inside it. (I updated to TL 2014, just to check that, and still getting the same error.)

What am I missing?

The code I'm testing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings=yes]{examplep}% this doesn't work
%\usepackage{examplep}% this does


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% This lstlisting has its own caption
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Caption of lstlisting},label=cod:c]
#include<iostream>

int main{
  std::cout << "Hello LaTeX\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}

% The lstlisting caption is not shown here
\begin{WBoth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++,caption={Caption of lstlisting}]
#include<iostream>

int main{
  std::cout << "Hello LaTeX\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{WBoth}
\PexaShowSource{}
\PexaShowSample{}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

I contacted the author of the package, and he kindly shared a version of the file with `listings` on it:  http://www.math.bme.hu/~pts/examplep_all.zip.

I'm trying to make it work, but as he pointed it out, the package is more than 8 years old. I'm trying to make it work, but still get several errors on the simple example above.

Probably someone with more experience can check what's going on. As right now I'm getting `\PexaShowSample` undefined control sequence errors.

Comment: The word "listings" doesn't appear in any of the style files related to the `examplep` package. The documentation (which refers to `listings` as a package option) seems to have been last modified in 2005, but the file `examplep.sty` was last modified at a later date (2010). This leads me to believe that the option in question may have been removed some time between 2005 and 2010, but the documentation was never altered to reflect that. You should get in touch with the author.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems that it can be definitively answered only by the author of the `examplep` package.

Comment: All packages supporting latex code together with the resulting compilation are listed at the (newly introduced) CTAN topic: https://ctan.org/topic/macro-demo

Comment: I added the source of the linked package at https://github.com/koppor/examplep